# Should there be a warning for new users before they type an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, new-users

Over on Arqade, a lot of new users will tend to show up who are willing to provide input but they may not have gotten the gist of things. This is understandable.

However, a lot of time, there will be people who haven't exactly gotten the hang of what the site is about at all.

[image: non-answer]

As you can see, there will tend to be a lot of users who haven't necessarily read the tour page, for example, to know how the site functions. There will also be, as you can see, people who use the answer feature without exactly understanding that they're not using it correctly.

So I've been thinking about how this could be avoided, and my idea was that we could have a warning for new users before they type up a question that explains how the answer feature should be used, with examples of what they should/shouldn't do.

**Would this be plausible?**

Comment: We have that on Stack Overflow - people have a page that they should read and indicate they have read and understood before they can go and ask a question. It doesn't really help - the people who post such questions are the kind of person who would just check the box without reading.

Comment: @Oded Just out of curiosity, what exactly does that page look like?

Comment: Didn't  [South Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park) have an episode where someone resembling Steve Jobs yells *Why won't it read, we need to fix that*

Comment: It looks like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ2E5.png

Comment: The general SE philosophy provides that Low Quality answers can be removed more readily than poorly phrased questions.  It follows there can be asymmetry in allowing new users to post answers without prompting while users (new or otherwise) trying to post a new question get some automated coaching (i.e. do any of these previous Questions already ask what you were about to?).

Answer (score 2):

I think you make a valid point. Oded pointed out in comments already that this is not going to be the holy grail that fixes all the issues, because that would mean we have to fix a part of the new comers just seeking the answer.

I think the current tour, help and 'before you ask a question' page are very helpful, but I wonder what can be done more. Maybe before someone tries to post their first *answer* they can get a small box asking if the answer is actually an answer according to our standards. That could link to a page that points out the differences between forums and Q/A.

This could help a lot of users not to post non-answers and keep a positive first-time experience on the site.

Comment: That could definitely work. I like your thought.

Comment: Again though, you're targeting bad users with tactics that only work on good users.

Comment: Well, *some* have good intentions. This is only going to fix the problem with good users. Bad users can't be helped as in my first paragraph. @James

Comment: The box could show something like "Before you post your answer, is it...", and then some guidelines for whatever site the user is on.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI indeed. Or SE in general if that is enough? Link-only answers are never allowed for example.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The guidelines shown would always contain things like "not a link-only answer", or any other general rule across SE. The reason I mention "whatever site the user is on" is because certain sites have special rules based on what they cover. For instance, Arqade doesn't accept what-if questions, but Worldbuilding does (assuming they're formatted properly).

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I thought the question was answer-specific.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is, but the same principle could apply to answers as well.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI This is correct in the sense that every site can have different guidelines alongside the general rules. Skeptics, for example, strictly requires their answers to give evidence to support a claim.